# Windows batch to change all IIS app pools time-out

Tags: windows, batch, iis

I want to change all IIS Pools time-out.
I'm using below command to get list of App Pool list.
`%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe list apppool /text:name`
After that I'm putting name of each app pool in below command to set time-out
`%APPCMD% set apppool /apppool.name:"BusinessReportAppPool" /processModel.idleTimeout:1:00:00`
But I'm looking for a batch file which
1. Search all available app pool
2. Then put the name in above command to change the time-out
I know it is possible using For loop in batch, but I'm don't know how to use it.
Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Loop through all app pool names

You can run the `AppCmd.exe` app pool list command through a [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop using `"tokens=*"` to get a list of all the app pool names. You can then loop through these output values and run those against the `AppCmd.exe` command and then set the idle timeout period for all the iterated app pools.

#### Batch Script

```
SET "APPCMD=%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe"
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%f IN ('%APPCMD% list apppool /text:name') DO %APPCMD% set apppool /apppool.name:"%%~f" /processModel.idleTimeout:1:00:00
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Getting Started with AppCmd.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe)